# Insert only unique data to db and export new data to csv

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

So, I have a local office that sends us a list of new subscribers from their location daily. But instead of just sending over the new data, they just send over a csv with what i think is the last 25,000 records - i'm guessing the clerk just clicks some default option.
I have a simple python script which inserts this data to a local mysql db, with sub_id set as unique index to prevent duplicates.
My problem however, is that I have to send the new subscriber data over to another team.
I want to add this functionality to the existing python script, and the solution I could think of is to add a "NEW" status when inserting to the db, and then export all rows with "NEW" status, and then update the "NEW" status to "EXPORTED".
This feels inefficient to me -
Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `created_at` timestamp to the table and send everything with a `created_at` greater than when the process started. This is the most robust option, and also adds a bit of information to the database which may be useful later; you can figure out which row was made by which import.

Or, have the Python script remember the IDs of every row it inserted. Then select only those rows.

Alternatively, have the Python script build the report as it inserts the data.

Comment: created_at timestamp is a great idea! I'll add that. But having the python script build the report while inserting will build a report with all 25,000 rows because INSERT IGNORE would ignore the duplicates and just insert the unique rows to the db?

Comment: @curious_ghost Depends on how you're doing the inserts. If you're doing them one at a time, you can check if it was inserted. If you're doing them in bulk that would be more difficult.

Comment: I'm doing one at a time with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. How would I check if it was inserted? I'm a beginner to mysql. so a code snippet would help

Comment: @curious_ghost The Python database interface should have a way to check how many rows were affected by the previous insert. I can't say more because I don't know what your code is doing.